# How to push google authentication data to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, google-signin

I followed **google developer docs** https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in  and created google sign-in for my site. *The next question is how do I get it to my database. I use mongodb.*

[image: Here's an image of my auth page as of now. (will style it later)]

```
Here's the link to my codepen which contains the auth code https://codepen.io/dingus45191/pen/yLaXZWW
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/dingus45191/pen/yLaXZWW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth
Firebase Authentication provides backend services, easy-to-use SDKs, and ready-made UI libraries to authenticate users to your app. It supports authentication using passwords, phone numbers, popular federated identity providers like Google, Facebook and Twitter, and more.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use "Passport js" : http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth2/

This module lets you authenticate using Google in your Node.js applications. By plugging into Passport, Google authentication can be easily and unobtrusively integrated into any application or framework that supports Connect-style middleware, including Express.

Comment: it throws error user is not defined when I copy code from docs

Comment: ah sorry I did not know